# Enable git merging between branches after conversion from svn

Tags: git, merge

We have converted an SVN repository into Git. In SVN people mostly synced bugfixes from our stable branch "release-2013" to the development branch (and vice versa) manually by file copy or Winmerge so no svn merge info existed and in Git the changes are unrelated. I'd like somehow to state "all changes in current head of release-2013 are already in master". Then I hope I can merge future bugfixes from release-2013 into master using normal git merge. Is this possible somehow?

Searching previous discussions gave me only graft points as something coming close to this, but I'm unsure if and how I can use them to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Might http://thomasrast.ch/git/git-svn-conversion.html under title "grafting merges" be the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating your "all changes in current head of release-2013 are already in master" wish into git syntax:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge -s ours release-2013
```

Making sure the differences between `release-2013` and `master` are actually what you think they are (with `git diff`) might be advisable.

Answer (score 1):

What I now did was the following:

- checkout master
- merge release-2013 (yes, this will give hundreds of conflicts)
- git status > status.txt
- for all lines in status.txt marked as deleted in ours do
  `git rm <file>`
- for all other files do 
  `git reset HEAD <file>` 
  `git checkout --ours -- <file>`
- Commit and push

Since then, I can merge new bug fixes done in the release-2013 branch back to master by simply merging release-2013 into master

Comment: How is that different from `git merge -s ours`?

Comment: It is more complicated and has more chance for errors. Joke aside, git merge -s ours is much easier and better. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?